# How to debug a Run-Time Error 13 in VBA?

Tags: vba, runtime-error

Here's my entire code below. I keep getting a Run-Time Error 13, any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button_Clear_Click()
    Input_Wager.Text = "0"
End Sub
```

The section below, I would like when the command button is pressed that if the Textbox `Input_Wager` is empty, it displays a message, otherwise it starts the computations in the `elseif` section

```
Private Sub Button_Submit_Click()
    If Me.Input_Wager.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Display")
    ElseIf Me.Input_Wager.Text <> "" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 35)
        TextBox3.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 17)
        TextBox4.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 8)
        TextBox5.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 11)
        TextBox6.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 6)
        TextBox7.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 5)
        TextBox8.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 11)
        TextBox9.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 17)
        TextBox10.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 2)
        TextBox11.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 2)
        TextBox12.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
        TextBox13.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
        TextBox14.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
        TextBox15.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
        TextBox16.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
        TextBox17.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager * 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the problem that you're concatenating a string and an integer?

Comment: Runtime error 13 means [Type Mismatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx). So you are operating on the wrong type of objects. For example, why are you multiplying a control by 35? You multiply numbers, not controls.

Comment: Apparently the contents of `Input_Wager` cannot be implicitly parsed as a number.

Answer (score -1):

As @Andrew and @Raymond said, you are getting a type mismatch error because you are trying to multiply a control/object with an Integer.

First check to see if the value of Input_Wager is an Integer and not a string - do this by not letting it accept anything else than an integer -

```
Private Sub Input_Wager_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles   Input_Wager.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)   Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Now that you know it has an integer value, change your multiplication lines to this -

```
TextBox2.Text = "$" & (Me.Input_Wager.Text * 35)
```

Comment: The OP is using VBA, and that is not a good way to restrict a field to numbers anyway (and it does not handle pasted values). If the OP was using VB.NET, a better approach would be `Integer.TryParse`.